# Auto row height adjustment in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to wrap my text inside the cell, so that the widths of all cells will be equal. The text should not be hidden after wrapping. Here's my table-

```
<table border="2" width="20px">
<tr>
<td>testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest</td>
<td>test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>test</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

With `wordwrap:break-word`, the text is getting hidden. Also I don't want a scroll bar.

How can that be achieved by CSS? Point me in right direction.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to set a width on the table, but you need to set a width on each table cell for the columns to have equal width.  Otherwise the cells will stretch to a width inside the table that's proportional to the size of the content.  Also, are you using this table to lay out your content?  This is considered a very bad practice.  Use div tags and CSS to make your layout, not tables.

Comment: Many designers strive to build [semantic HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML).  This means that the HTML code is there to enhance the meaning of the content, not determine the look and layout.  CSS, on the other hand, is a tool to build the look and layout.  Separating the two means you can change the look without touching the meaning, and you can change the meaning without touching the look.  It usually means producing less HTML code which results in faster pageloads and also tends to mean Google will favor you a bit as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fekSg/. Use fixed for table layout, and make all the td elements wrap

```
<style>
td {
word-wrap: break-word;
}
</style>
<table border="2" width="100px" style='table-layout:fixed;'>
<tr>
<td>testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest</td>
<td>test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>test</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: yes it is, no need to thank the superman. but that won't stop him from finding you and taking they checkmark BY FORCE

Comment: nah he has people to save, Sans .. gives the checkmark, to superman who helped save his day with simple css solutions

Comment: techjunkie.css, give my checkmark to superman. tell him that spiderman gave :)